# Getting at a XML nodes with Minidom

Tags: python, minidom

I'm trying to parse an XML file with the following structure using minidom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Product> 
   <Product version='1'> 
      <Name>My Product</Name> 
    <Type>Physical</Type>
    <Stock>2</Visibility>     
</Product>
```

So far, I've got something like this:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse(file)
name = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Name')
print name[0].nodeValue
```

But this returns None. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was missing firstChild:

print name[0].firstChild.nodeValue